# Getting a FALSE message at the bottom of my Rshiny output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to Rshiny.  I've written this code:

```
ui=source('./www/uixx2.R')

server = function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The uixx2.R file is placed in the subdirectory www and the code is:

ui=shinyUI("Why am i getting:  ")
```

The output is:
**Why am i getting:  FALSE**

I keep getting FALSE at the bottom of my output everytime I use the source function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to the ui variable twice. The line `ui =  source('./www/uixx2.R')` is creating the error, since the ui becomes a list of the sourced code and FALSE, which then shiny displays. Check it in the variable viewer.

Generally the source("file.R") should not be used to assign to a variable since it has no defined return value. (or at least in the usual ? help it doesn't say anything)

This one works.

```
source('./www/uixx2.R')    
server = function(input,output){}    
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The uixx2.R file is placed in the subdirectory www and the code is:    
ui=shinyUI("Why am i getting:  ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the following: In RStudio, go to file -> New file -> Shiny Web App

That way, it will automatically set up a structure for you and make it hard to go wrong

But to answer the question, your `ui` can be a function, like so

```
ui <- source('./www/uixx2.R')[[1]] # This takes the first list item (i.e. the function - see below)

server = function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

# In uixx2.R, simply put:

function() {
  shinyUI("Why am i getting: ")
  # Anything else goes here ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: It needs not be a function. Since the OP is using a list ui and it still works. With unintended consequences, sure, but it is a list :-).

Comment: I wanted to say simple thanks, however the comment would be shorter than 15 characters. So you are getting this "essay" :-).

Comment: Thanks all.  Really helped me understand what’s going on.